# Vercel deployment: Error occurred prerendering page "/" TypeError: fetch failed

Tags: javascript, vercel, sanity

Yesterday I deployed my project (using Sanity.io) to Vercel and no issue.

Today I edited my code and want to deploy the new version with this commands:

```
vercel build
```

```
vercel deploy --prebuilt
```

```
vercel --prod
```

The last command gave me an error message:

[vercel error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzGbG.png)

And it's seem the error comes from fetchPageInfo.js

*fetchPageInfo.js*

```
export const fetchPageInfo = async() => {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/getPageInfo`);
    const data = await res.json();
    const pageInfo: PageInfo = data.pageInfo
    
    return pageInfo;
```

*index.tsx*

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<Props> = async () => {
  const pageInfo: PageInfo = await fetchPageInfo();
  const experience: Experience[] = await fetchExperience();
  const skills: Skill[] = await fetchSkills();
  const projets: Projet[] = await fetchProjet();
  const socials: Social[] = await fetchSocial();
  return {
    props: {
      pageInfo,
      experience,
      skills,
      projets,
      socials,
    },
    revalidate:10,
  };
};
```

*env.local*

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET =  production
NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID = *<hideContent>*
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL = http://localhost:3000/
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

I'm new on Sanity and Vercel and I suppose that Sanity and Vercel communicated together and Vercel convert NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL to the real URL and not the local

I tried to directly pass the projetId key in the sanity.ts and put the real online URL in the fetchPageInfo (this edit gave me this error: **Failed to parse URL from undefined/api/getExperience**

But when I put the URL in Safari I retrieved all the data.

So I'm stuck...

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: I am also having the same issue, but I'm getting this same error, but `vercel build` itself is failing for me.  By any chance, have you found any fix?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by following the below steps:

- Added `NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL = "Vercel URL goes here instead of localhost"`
- Replaced fetch requests with axios requests at all utility files (fetch requests have some default timeouts)
- Added `staticPageGenerationTimeout: 200,` at next.config.js

You have to remember:

> With NextJS, client is server is **ONE**

This is the reason NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL has to be the **final** deployment URL of your project instead of localhost.

> Note: The last two actions I made to solve the problem, (axios and staticPage timeout) are due to the fact that my internet connection is slow